# Is a PriorityQueue appropriate for this case?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I've got a class which is little more than a pair `(double, int)`. I need to keep two collections of these objects, both sorted by the `double`, one in ascending order and the other in descending order.

Example:

```
asc: [(4.0, 10), (4.5, 8), (5.2, 13), (6.0, 1)]
des: [(32.0, 20), (27.5, 2), (13.65, 4), (6.0, 100)]
```

The main usage pattern will be:

1. Client enters with a pair `(d, i)`;
2. Check the head of one of the collections (depends on the client) for a pair *lower* (resp. *higher*), with respect to `d`, than the given pair;
3. If it exists, either remove it or perform some calculations, based on the value of `i`;
4. If it doesn't exist, or it wasn't removed, insert the given pair in the other collection, in the appropriate place.

So, the main operations are:

- Insert in order;
- Retrieve head;
- Remove head.

Example:

1. Client enters with `(4.2, 12)` and wants to look at `asc`;
2. `asc` has a pair with `4.0`, which is lower than `4.2`;
3. Remove head of `asc` and look at the new head;
4. The new head is higher than `4.2`, so the client inserts the pair in `des`, at the tail, since `4.2` is lower than `6.0`.

Since no client wants to traverse the collection, but rather process the current head, and since insertions have to be in order and quite fast, **I'd say a `PriorityQueue` is the tool for the job.**

Am I right, or is there a better data-structure in Java (**no external libraries**) that I'm not aware of?

An `ArrayList`, for instance, sounds terrible for this task, since insertions would happen at a *random* index, as opposed to inserting at the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Insert in order

`PriorityQueue.add()` does that.

> - Retrieve head

`PriorityQueue.peek()` does that.

> - Remove head

`PriorityQueue.poll()` or `PriorityQueue.remove()` does that.

Seems like a perfect fit to me.

Comment: Indeed, it seems. As I was writing the question, the use cases became clearer, and I ended up just wondering if there was any other suitable alternative. But I guess the description of my problem clearly indicates a `PriorityQueue`.